# Multidimensional Array not Retrieving Value

Tags: php, arrays

I am using php/noloh to create a tic tac toe game. NONE is a constant defined as -1.

```
// Set up an empty 
$this->grid = array();
for ( $y = 0; $y < 3; $y++ ) {
    for ( $x = 0; $x < 3; $x++ ) {
        $this->grid[y][x] = NONE;
    }
}       
System::Alert($this->grid[0][0]);
```

The system alert is just displaying an empty message. Nothing is assigned in it apparently I guess. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You forgot to add the `$` in front of your variable names.

Comment: What is the none? did you tried to assign to a number?

Comment: @demonofnight OP said NONE is defined as -1.

Comment: @Jack Thanks! PHP is an unfamiliar language to me.

Comment: It would be a good idea to initialise each `$this->grid[$y]` as an array